# Best Eclipse Plugins for java development making use of spring/ struts /hibernate?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for plugins which make developer's life easy while using technologies like Struts/ Spring/ Hibernate. For instance, here is a requirement:

If I were to change an Struts Action, I should be able to list out all the Struts Actions for my webapp, right click and add a method/ do some changes.

So, basically, I need to know what plugins will make eclipse more 'technology/framework friendly'.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Struts? 2003 just called. They want their Web framework back. :)

Comment: LOL, Struts 2 is a little progressive.  Still, I prefer Spring MVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Spring IDE](http://springide.org/blog/).  It has support for the Spring basics plus a few associated libraries, and is available as an Eclipse plugin download from http://springide.org/updatesite/.  Once installed, you apply a Spring nature to the project in order to use it.

Hibernate also has [Hibernate Tools](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html) available, but I've never checked that out to see how it works.  From the description, it apparently offers some functions to make creating and editing mapping files easier.

As far as I can tell, Struts doesn't have anything up-to-date as far as IDE plugins go.  [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com) may have something like that.

Side note: for some reason, I've never stuck with the plugins for these libraries.  I gave the Spring one a try once, but eventually got used to editing the Spring configs manually and haven't touched it in a while.  I don't know how much of a benefit they would be for increasing config file creation... although they probably would help in visualizing dependencies in a big set of Spring configs.

Comment: I've actually used Hibernate Tools and it's great.

Answer (score 3):

Spring tools suite is great for this. You might also look into [Fast Code Eclipse Plugin](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind paying the price ($31.75 for standard, $63.55 for pro), you could check out [MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.org/). This is a nice and powerful "extension" of Eclipse that has many nice [features](http://www.myeclipseide.org/module-htmlpages-display-pid-1.html), including Spring Tools, Struts (and Struts 2), Hibernate and many more.

Comment: MyEclipse is more and more obsolete with years. There are really a *lot* of free Eclipse plugins available the last years.